# Dynamic URI to load entry template

Tags: craft3, templating, routing

This may be asking the impossible, but I'm trying to do the following:
Say I have 3 channels, Country, Region, and Town. Town has an entry field to select a Region, a Region entry has a field to select a Country.

I want the URL for a Town entry to look like https://website.something/uk/west/torquay, or https://website.something/portugal/south/faro. Both of these URLs would load the template specified for the town. A URL of https://website.something/france/south would load a Region template.

I'm guessing I'll have to do some advanced routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely possible without any extra routing!

First you would need to make sure the relation fields are required to prevent any errors.

For the `Country` section, you would simply set up your section with the URI format `{ slug }`

For `Region` you would set up the URI Format to grab the related Country's slug for the first segment, like this: `{ yourCountryFieldHandle.one().slug }/{ slug }`

And for `Town` it would be `{ yourRegionFieldHandle.one().yourCountryFieldHandle.one().slug }/{ yourRegionFieldHandle.one().slug }/{ slug }` which gets the related Region's Country for the first segment, then the related Region for the second.

You can then specify a different template for each section.

Comment: Wow! It's a bit late for me, but doing a quick test this looks to work exactly how I'm hoping!

I'll give it a better check on Monday, and will mark as answer when I'm more awake. Either way, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck!

Comment: Seems all good so far. Need to test some more, but so far it's exactly what I'm after.
Thank you!

On a side note, it's dramatically changed how I think the URI format works. I'm sure this will help with other projects. Re-reading the docs I can see how your answer works, but I think you have it better explained.

Comment: Yes – it was a big deal when I realised I could use field values in URL format, and dynamic entry titles. The second best option would be to use the same template for all sections that reads segment 2+3 for region/town and changes the template appropriately (or redirects to another template). You could do it with routing for sure, but you'd miss out on the tighter integration with Craft – so no live preview etc.